# How does initialization to a value compare in performance to assignment?

Tags: c++, performance

I read that for user-defined types, postponing the defintion of a variable until a suitable initializer is available can lead to better performance.
why?

Comment: I'd do it just because your code becomes much more concise and cleaner. It doesn't make sense to define a variable and then not use it until later.

Comment: @GMan: That's another good point. The smaller the range of a variables usage, the easier it is to follow the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *user-defined* types in particular, the constructor and setting method could me arbitrarily complex and time-consuming.  Taking Steven's example:

```
X x; // Calls X() 
x.Set(42); 

X x(42); // Calls X(int)
```

... the implementation of X::X() and X::Set() might ***both*** be very time-consuming, and *that's* why you read that the latter can have better performance.

Answer (score 3):

Because it means a constructor other than the default constructor is called.

```
X x; // Calls X()
x.Set(42);

X x(42); // Calls X(int)
```

Comment: I doubt you'd find much of a performance difference, though, except in more complex cases.

Comment: @GMan: True, although a deeper issue would be classes that can *only* be initialized, never assigned. These immutable classes have become much more common as of late, due to the rise of parallelism.

Comment: @GMan: It's both. Actually, I think Neil's example is better than mine, because it shows how we're avoiding a memory allocation.

Answer (score 3):

Consider  a string class. If we say:

```
string s;
....
s = "foobar";
```

then we have to do  some work in the construction of s, and then more or less repeat the same work in the assignment. If we do:

```
string s( "foobar" );
```

we do the work once only.

Having said that, when learning C++ you should *never* concern yourself with issues of performance - think only about writing clear and understandable code. And in this case, initialisation with a value also wins out - code is clearer if variables are always initialised.

And BTW, the language is called C++ - cpp is the C preprocessor.

Comment: Ironically, the first implementation of C++ was a translator into C; essentially just a pre-processor. :-)

Comment: @Steven No it wasn't - I used it - it was  a compiler (not  a translator or  a pre-processor) which emitted C as it's target language. I wish this myth would die.

Comment: @Neil - that's interesting to know. At least on my case my first experience with C++ was CFront (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) and I believe it was in fact a pre-processor.

Comment: @Neil: A compiler which emits C would be considered a translator.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Umm.. how exactly compiler that emits C code (i.e. not machine code) is different from preprocessor? To me it looks like they do almost same thing...

Comment: @Otávio: Yes, I was referring to Cfront. Thanks for mentioning the name.

Comment: No, it was a compiler - there is nothing that says a compiler cannot emit C - the original Eiffel compiler also did this. A preprocessor like CPP can only so one to-one translations between symbols, whereas  a compiler does the whole parsing, semantic analysis, code generation, optimisation thing. The predecessor of C++, C With Classes was implemented as a preprocessor. For confirmation and more details Read Stroustrup's D&E book.

Comment: @Steven - on a DEC-VAX btw. Makes me feel quite old. Sigh. @Neil - in that sense you are quite correct. However I always heard of CFront with the word preprocessor close by.

Comment: Look, it's technically both a translator and a source-to-source compiler. Cfront was more sophisticated than CPP, but it shared the common property of generating C code. This is why Cfront is often compared to preprocessors. For example, Stephen Dewhurst, who worked on Cfront and on the next few C++ implementations, casually referred to it as "essentially a preprocessor". Unfortunately, that quote was from a conversation we had while we were coworkers, so I can't link to a reference.

Comment: @Steven I prefer to take Stroustrup's word, and in the D&E book he explicitly states that is was not a preprocessor, but  a true compiler.

Comment: @Neil: You do what you like, but if Dewhurst admits it was "essentially a pre-processor", then I feel quite comfortable describing it the same way. I never denied that it was technically a (source-to-source) compiler, so this is not so much a matter of actual disagreement as your being unhappy with my choice of words.

Comment: Straight from the horses's mouth (http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_1.0/src/cfront/README/view) - it is a translator- "ident "@(#)cfront:README 1.4"
This is the AT&T C++ Translator, Release 1.0."

Comment: @Otavio From another horse, see Stroustrup, D&E book, section 3.3.1 - "C++ cannot be compiled with any traditional preprocessor technology". And other similar statements.

Comment: In my experience, a 'translator' produces code that is (ideally) as readble as the source.  It preserves comments, structure, and variable names as much as possible, like the old `p2c` translator.  A compiler that targets C (or some other language) makes no attempt to produce readable output.  CFront was definitely NOT a translator

Answer (score 1):

You avoid running an unnecessary constructor followed by an Init call when the proper initialization data is available. And, if the code path never reaches the initialization branch you can avoid the constructor and destructor all together, plus an exception handling state setup for the unwinding.

Comment: Good point. How often have you seen a function that declares a bunch of variables at the top, and then immediately exits because a parameter is null? (rhetorical question)